# Facebook Android SDk post to my wall with Native FaceBook App or through web brwoser if FB app is not present

Tags: android, facebook

I want to put in may application a button which will give a possibility for the user to input some message and post it on his wall. My question is, how to implement this scenario:

1. User enters message and clicks Share button.
2. If Native FaceBook app is present on the device, it is fired in order to post this message, or to login first and give permissions.
3. If Native FaceBook app is NOT present on the device, web browser is fired and redirected to facebook page in order to login and post a message. (Or popup with WebView instead of web browser app)

Comment: have you used the facebook sdk?

Comment: I know about it, I looked through the documentation, but I don;t know how to use it with this scenario. I know how to post a message to the wall, but I don't know how to implement this checking: if native fb app present go there, if not use web.

Comment: actually if device is having facebook app installed you will be taken to the installed FB app otherwise it will give you a popup for login ID and password

Comment: in the document they also provide sample project you can refer that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the sample project link https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

and the tutorial link is : http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/28/30-minute-guide-integrating-facebook-android-application/